# probably wood for trees - mysql won't return fulldataset

Tags: php, sql

I run the following from php and I get the first record in the table and that's it, an array containing exactly one element.

```
$sql = 'SELECT id FROM users';  
$pass = mysql_query($sql);  
var_dump($pass);  

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($pass);  
var_dump($row);
```

But the exact same sql fed straight into the database gives me the full dataset, over 300 records. So what the flip am I doing wrong with the php?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to loop through each row:

```
$sql = 'SELECT id FROM users';  
$pass = mysql_query($sql);  

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($pass) ) {
    var_dump($row); 
}
```

Comment: it was, it was wood for the trees, thank you for leading me out of it :)